# PHP - Getting a selection from a dropdown box for use in another dropdown box on the same page

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I am trying to populate a dropdown box using the selection from another dropdown box. I have already figured out how to populate the list using data from the database, it seems the problem is in getting what they have selected from the first dropdown box on the same page without submitting the form. This is what I have so far.

```
<select name = "trainer_has_update_pokemon">
<p>Trainer</p>
<?php
$query = "SELECT name FROM Trainer";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo"<option>$name</option>";
}


$stmt->close();
}


?>
</select>

<?php
$trainer_name = $_GET['trainer_has_update_pokemon'];
?>

<p>Pokemon</p>
<select name = "type_of_update_pokemon">
<?php
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM Pokemon p WHERE p.owner_id = (SELECT t.trainer_id FROM Trainer t WHERE t.name = '$trainer_name')";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($pkmn_name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo"<option>$pkmn_name</option>";
}
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

I don't really have any experience in Javascript or AJAX, so if there is a way to do this without those, that would be helpful, but if not, I am open to learning their application in this case.

Comment: No there is no other way than AJAX (aside the way of loading your whole database on the initial page load, and then just changing the combobox with javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need some sort of client side script to call an external php page in order to pull in the data in real-time. A quick mock up would look something like:

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ //document ready
    $('select[name="trainer_has_update_pokemon"]').change(function(){ // when trainer_has_update_pokemon changes
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", //send a post method
            url:'ajax.php', // path to ajax page
            data:"trainer_name="+$(this).val(), //set trainer_name to value
            success:function(response){ // retrieve response from php
                $('select[name="type_of_update_pokemon"]').html(response); // update select
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP (i've named ajax.php):

```
<?php
/* ADD YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION */
$trainer_name = $_POST['trainer_name']; // DONT FORGET TO ESCAPE!!
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM Pokemon p WHERE p.owner_id = (SELECT t.trainer_id FROM Trainer t WHERE t.name = '$trainer_name')";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($pkmn_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo"<option>$pkmn_name</option>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}?>
```

Comment: I follow what you are doing with the JS and ajax, and i've adapted my code to use it, but it still leaves the dropdown box empty once I have selected a trainer. And I am sure I have pokemon on the database, and I have used the phpMyAdmin to test my SQL query.

Comment: A couple of suggestions. Use the console tab from firebug (in Firefox), to make sure the request is completing successfully. Next, try using `alert(response)` just above: `$('input[name="type_of_update_pokemon"]').html(response);` and inside the `success:function(){}`

Comment: I looked at it using the firebug console and nothing comes up at all for any of it.
And what should I be getting from the `alert(response)` part?

Comment: Something will only show in the console when you change the first select. And, your alert should show anything that you echo from your ajax.php page

Comment: Nothing comes up in the console when I change the first select, and so because it doesn't seem to get that I am changing the select, it doesnt send anything to the ajax.php page or return anything.

Comment: Yes I apologize. You need to replace input with select in the JavaScript. You are changing selects not inputs. Sorry. Updating code in just a second

Comment: Works great now! Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: great glad to hear. JQuery is a powerful addition to JavaScript and it's easy to learn. I highly recommend